# Running Antlr4 parser with lexer grammar gets token recognition errors

Tags: parsing, antlr4

I'm trying to create a grammar to parse Solr queries (only mildly relevant and you don't need to know anything about solr to answer the question -- just know more than I do about antlr 4.7).  I'm basing it on the QueryParser.jj file from solr 6.  I looked for an existing one, but there doesn't seem to be one that isn't old and out-of-date.

I'm stuck because when I try to run the parser I get "token recognition error"s.

The lexer I created uses lexer modes which, as I understand it means I need to have a separate lexer grammar file. So, I have a parser and a lexer file.

I whittled it down to a simple example to show I'm seeing.  Maybe someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.  Here's the parser (Junk.g4):

```
grammar Junk;

options {
  language = Java;
  tokenVocab=JLexer;
}

term : TERM '\r\n';
```

I can't use an import because of the lexer modes in the lexer file I'm trying to create (the tokens in the modes become "undefined" if I use an import).  That's why I reference the lexer file with the tokenVocab parameter (as shown in the XML example in github).

Here's the lexer (JLexer.g4):

```
lexer grammar JLexer;

TERM : TERM_START_CHAR TERM_CHAR* ;

TERM_START_CHAR : [abc] ;  
TERM_CHAR : [efg] ; 
WS  : [ \t\n\r\u3000]+ -> skip;
```

If I copy the lexer code into the parser, then things work as expected (e.g., "aeee" is a term).  Also, if I run the lexer file with grun (specifying tokens as the target), then the string parses as a TERM (as expected).

If I run the parser ("grun Junk term -tokens"), then I get:

```
line 1:0 token recognition error at: 'a'
line 1:1 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:2 token recognition error at: 'e'
line 1:3 token recognition error at: 'e'
[@0,4:5='\r\n',<'
'>,1:4]
```

I "compile" the lexer first, then "compile" the parser and then javac the resulting java files.  I do this in a batch file, so I'm pretty confident that I'm doing this every time.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.  Is it the way I'm running grun?  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Always trust your intuition! There is some convention internal to `grun` :-) See here [TestRig.java](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/gui/TestRig.java) c. lines 125, 150. Would have been lot nicer if some additional CLI args were also added.

When lexer and grammar are compiled separately, the grammar name - in your case - would be (insofar as `TestRig` goes) "Junk" and the two files must be named "JunkLexer.g4" and "JunkParser.g4". Accordingly the headers in parser file `JunkParser.g4` should be modified too

```
parser grammar JunkParser;
options { tokenVocab=JunkLexer; }
... stuff
```

Now you can run your tests

```
> antlr4 JunkLexer
> antlr4 JunkParser
> javac Junk*.java
> grun Junk term -tokens
aeee
^Z
[@0,0:3='aeee',<TERM>,1:0]
[@1,6:5='<EOF>',<EOF>,2:0]
>
```

Comment: This little bit of info helped me compile the XML grammar...thanks... ;)